# Are there any notification widgets for android that show the number of missed calls, messages, etc. just like on the regular notification screen?

Tags: notifications, app-widgets

Are there any notification widgets for android that show the number of missed calls, messages, etc. just like on the regular notification screen?

I'm currently using widget locker to customize my home screen but it also means that i can't tell if i have missed any calls or messages without having to unlock the phone. I would love to have a widget that i could put only on the widget locker lock screen just to quickly see if I've missed anything.

Edit: I'm on a captivate, 2.1 unrooted.

Comment: What version of Android are you using? Which phone? Are you rooted?

Answer (score 3):

Take a look at [GOTO Lock Screen](http://www.gotoandroidapp.com/index.html)- supposedly it is fast. It lets you stay on top of your text messages, missed calls, and Gmail notifications all with a simple slide gesture.

A detailed feature list is [available here](http://www.gotoandroidapp.com/features.html).

Re-reading your question, I see you want widgets to use in conjunction with WidgetLocker - what sms app are you using? Handcent has a medium sized widget which shows unread sms as does GoSMS. You can show missed calls using this [Call Log widget.](http://www.appbrain.com/app/missed-calls-widget/com.gonzo.MissCalls)

**UPDATE:** I do believe I've found something that might interest you - [PureMessenger](https://market.android.com/details?id=org.koxx.pure_messenger) widget will show the following:

- Gmail
- Emails (POP3+IMAP / need K9FP)
- SMS
- Facebook
- Twitter
- Calls

Comment: I was wondering if there was a simple widget that just showed 3 or 4 customizable icons that displayed how many sms, phone calls, emails, or calender events i've missed. Every time my phone vibrates I have to unlock it to figure out what just happened. Widgets because I love how widget locker allows for so much lock screen customization by allowing widgets to be displayed but not interactable.

Answer (score 1):

I'd suggest NoLed, a pretty handy and battery-efficient way to see notifications of missed events while the phone is locked. Minimal battery drain on AMOLED screens and pretty customizable.